# Multiplying numbers by certain number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I`m trying to multiply integer by 1.1765

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jo06fR0KrZXs6p82tjjuGmOVI0JsVFr3jsT_B5Efn6Y/edit?usp=sharing

Above is the sample data

So i`m trying to multiply pre-spend column to 1.1765

The Actual Spend will be Pre-spend * 1.1765

I tried the below code

```
function multiply(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newspend = sheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,1).getValues()*1.1765;
  var rng = sheet.getRange(2,2,sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  Logger.log(newspend)
  rng.setValues(newspend)
}
```

But I get an error message saying,

> Cannot find method setValues(number)

I think this is because things are not in array..?

How should we tackle this?

Comment: Currently you're trying to multiply a whole array. You should do it for each individual array item instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than try and insert a value in those cells, you can use `setFormula` to insert a formula.

This answer is probably only one of several possible approaches.

---

```
function applyformula(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row is "+lastRow);
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1,2,lastRow-1,2);
  Logger.log("the data range = "+dataRange.getA1Notation());
  var variable = 1.1765;
  sheet.getRange(2,2,lastRow-1,1).setFormula("=A2*"+variable)
}
```

---

**Screenshot**
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Does A2 automatically change to A3 and so on based on range?

Comment: Yep. For example the content of Cell B6 = `=A6*1.1765`

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that.

Comment: Couldn`t think of this approach.. it works perfectly! Thank you Tedinoz :)

Answer (score 0):

formula approach has been never easier. paste in B2:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,A2:A*1.1765))
```